# How to input realtime data into NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, real-time

I am just starting to learn Next.js framework.

I need help to solve a problem that I do not understand right now. In normal Vanilla JavaScript and React I can display the resulting API in HTML using the `setInterval` method.

My API changes data in **every 3 seconds**. I want to incorporate such variable data into my Next.js app.

Below I have combined the two APIs into a single props to carry data to other components.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const [twoDApiRes, saveApiRes] = await Promise.all([
        fetch(_liveResult),
        fetch(_localTxt),
    ]);

    const [twoDApi, saveApi] = await Promise.all([
        twoDApiRes.json(),
        saveApiRes.text(),
    ]);

    // Regex
    let csv_data = saveApi.split(/\r?\n|\r/);

    // Loop through
    const retrieveData = csv_data.map((el) => {
        let cell_data = el.split(',');

        return cell_data;
    });

    return {
        props: { twoDApi, retrieveData },
    };
}
```

[image]

The main thing to know is that you want to change the data **every three seconds** in Next.js `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: create a custom hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` hook to refresh data every 3 seconds.

```js
// This function will return Promise that resolves required data
async function retrieveData() {
  // retrieves data from the server
}

function MyPage() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState(Math.random());
  
  useEffect(() => {
    retriveData()
      .then(setData)
      .finally(() => {
        // Update refreshToken after 3 seconds so this event will re-trigger and update the data
        setTimeout(() => setRefreshToken(Math.random()), 3000);
      });
  }, [refreshToken]);

  return <div>{data?.name}</div>
}
```

Or you can use [`react-query`](https://react-query.tanstack.com/overview) library with `{refetchInterval: 3000}` options to refetch data every 3 seconds.

Here's [an example](https://react-query.tanstack.com/examples/auto-refetching#_top) for using **react-query**.

Comment: I appreciate it for showing alongside with an example. Do you have any elegant ways to fetch the data which I have the two api url?

Comment: You can either use Promise.all to call APIs in parallel or combine requests into one request on backend side (to reduce server side requests = faster load time = better user experience) but it requires changes to backend. I would be probably do what you've already because I'm too lazy to consider changing backend to reduce load time by 200 milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I could understand well what did you explain up above along with an examples. The reason why I am choosing "getServerSideProps" because I don't want any api request endpoint to the end users be able to see my XHR request in the network tap via using browers console. Otherwise they will use my api without any confirmation. If you guide me how do implementation of using within the "ServerSideProps" like so, then I will be very happy.

Comment: @PJK unfortunately it's not possible to achieve this using getServerSideProps function because this function only runs when the page loads. After that you have to update data on client-side. If you don't want to expose your api keys to public you can write simple api server function (check this: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) and call that function on your client side.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation such a great with useful tips.

Comment: You can check this example repl for the example next.js api: https://repl.it/@misir_ceferov/nextJS-api-autoreload

Comment: ` import { articles } from '../../../data';

export default function handler(req, res) {
 res.status(200).json(articles);
}
 `

@TheMisir, This is how I learnt to export my javasctipt object as an **json api**. But, I want to retrieve the data from this endpoint which '**https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts**', then call it from my client, Can you guide me how do I implement this?

Comment: @PJK I've updated previous example. Check this repl.it: https://replit.com/@misir_ceferov/nextJS-api-autoreload

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch data every 3 seconds in next js 13 or latest App Router

```
 import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Page = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      fetch(`https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets/bitcoin`, { cache: 'no-store' })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setData(data));
    }, 3000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p>Symbol: {data?.data?.symbol}</p>
        <p>Name: {data?.data?.name}</p>
        <p>Price: {data?.data?.priceUsd}</p>
        <p>Market Cap: {data?.data?.marketCapUsd}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Page;
```